# Initial "jumpy" dragging behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

The following code creates a background and a rectangle. The rectangle can be dragged:

```
var p = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
} 

var width = 400
var height = 400

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)

svg.append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'bg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on('drag', dragmove)

svg.append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'btn')
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 50)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + p.x + ',' + p.y + ')')
  .call(drag)

function dragmove (d) {
  var x = d3.event.x
  var y = d3.event.y
  d3.select(this)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')')
}
```

The dragging event works, but there's an initial "jump" each time I drag the object (e.g the rectangle starts on the left of the cursor and then suddenly jumps to the right).

You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/alexcheninfo/5rnv7ww5/

What is causing it and how to prevent it (make the rectangle being dragged smoothly from the beginning)?

Comment: It's because it's following mouse coords. If you click on the very left-top corner of the square, it doesn't jump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be this way:

```
//get the translate on the dragged rectangle
var translate = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")).translate;
//to that add the mouse move deltax 
                x = d3.event.dx + translate[0],
                y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5rnv7ww5/1/)

when you do

```
var x = d3.event.x
  var y = d3.event.y
  d3.select(this)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')')
```

It will translate the rectangle to the mouse position thus the jump.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed that position of the mouse was right in the pointing part. I didn't expect the position to be behind. Or maybe it's because the center of the rectangle is not in the middle but in the top left corner.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify [origin](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Drag-Behavior.md#origin) of the drag behaviour. By default the underlying data object is used. In you case - it's the `p` object. So you would need to do this:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function() { return p; })
    .on('drag', dragmove)
```

and update it's x and y properties on every drag

```
function dragmove (d) {
    // ...
    // normally you would update d.x and d.y
    p.x = d3.event.x;
    p.y = d3.event.y;
    // ...
}
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yamewq5v/1).

In d3 v4 this is called [drag subject](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md#drag_subject).

Answer (score 1):

For those who struggling this, my 50 cents. In d3 js v7 there is no event.dx or event.dy properties, instead you have to read `event.movementX` and `event.movementY` properties. Here is my working code (I only needed x position). The `getTokenizedTransformAttributeValue` method is taken from here: https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/javascript/sustitucion-de-d3.transform-en-d3-v4/825493251/

```
self=this; 
const consty = 100; //example
let dragHandler = this.d3.drag()
     .on("drag", function() {
          const inputTrasformString = self.d3.select(this).attr("transform");
          var transformObject = self.getTokenizedTransformAttributeValue(inputTrasformString);     
          x = event.movementX+parseInt(transformObject.translate[0])
                     
          self.d3.select(this)
              .attr("transform", "translate("+x+","+consty+")");
          }).on("start",function() {
        //something
                }).on("end", function() {
        //something
              });
            
dragHandler(svg.select(".myclass"));
```